# Request for tags merging

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I'm mainly visiting [entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework) and [entity-framework-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-4) tags. These tags are ok but there are four related tags used to describe the same:

- [codefirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codefirst) (15 questions)
- [code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-first) (220 questions)
- [ef-code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) (120 questions)
- [ef4-code-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef4-code-only) (56 questions)

I think at least first two and second two should be merged. The reason why these tags should not be merged into one is because code-first is not related only to EF.

**Edit:**

I have just found that there is one more tag used for the same:

- [code-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-only) (29 questions)