# Version Specific and Generalized Tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, version-tags

Well, it seems as if there's no good way to put this (as this question [has been asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags), but ... from the other side of the hill, if that makes sense).  Basically, my question is not about tag creation, but about tag usage or even (god forbid, collective gasp) ***tag deletion***.

Example comparisons: (delineated by spaces)

- Flex Flex4 Flex-4 Flex-4.5 Flex4.5 Flex4.5.1 Adobe-Flex
- Adobe-Flashbuilder Flashbuilder flash-builder

Also consider this dilemma / example:

- flash actionscript-3 flash-builder flashbuilder4 [aforementioned flex tags here]

I've found that the only way to get a question regarding Flex to be answered, is to tag it with the following:

Flex Flex4.5 f lash-builder [actual topic of question]

**Generally Accepted Problems**

- Version Tags:

  - makes "favourite" and "ignored" tags almost useless.  Unless you only know a specific "version" of that programming language (?)
  - gives the question significantly less exposure if the author (in the spirit of not duplicating tags) **only** uses the language specific tag.

**Possible Solutions**

Unfortunately, the only solution I can see at the moment is that if versions were (somehow) sub-tags of the actual language tags.  This solution would have serious implementation issues, but it's all I can think of.

Comment: Similar proposal has been made, which appears to be somewhat better, so closing this one as dupe instead of other way around.

Answer (score 4):

I have another possible solution:

> Have the system automatically add (or suggest you add) the generalized tag to your post.  Possibly displaying a message encouraging the user to do it themselves, explaining that as some people don't know about tag* favouriting, their question might not get as much exposure as it should if they only have the version specific tag.

I cannot think of a set of tags (general, version) that this solution would not help.  However, examples of tags this would help are below:

<kbd>flash-builder4</kbd> ->> + <kbd>flash-builder</kbd>

<kbd>flex4</kbd> ->> + <kbd>flex</kbd>

<kbd>flex4.5</kbd> ->> + <kbd>flex</kbd>

Comment: And maybe even [tag:flex4.5] ->> +[tag:flex4]?

Answer (score 1):

We have the [synonym system](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) to take care of the "Adobe-Flashbuilder/Flashbuilder/flash-builder" issue.

What if we allowed a single level of subtagging? Something similar to this mockup:

[image: enter link description here]

I proposed this as a solution to [this problem](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/rename-the-legend-of-heroes-tits-tag), with expand-on-mouseover, but a similar looking [flex|4] tag could basically be a "two tags in one" feature, where the [flex] is implicit.