# Should version-specific tags be synonyms for the main tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I've seen this question - [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags) - But it doesn't address whether synonyms should be created or not.  The accepted answer just says that version-specific tags should be avoided unless it is an essential part of the question.

I am having trouble deciding if I should propose tag synonyms, particularly for version-specific TeamCity tags.

The purpose of tag synonyms (according to [the privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)) seems to be:

> What are tag synonyms?
>   Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with the correct tags.

While I wouldn't say that version-specific tags are always incorrect, I think they'd often be misused, and should *always* be paired with the "master" tag.  This is why a tag synonym makes sense to me.  But maybe I am misunderstanding the point of tag synonyms.  Are they just to correct things like typos (`modelling` vs `modeling`), or give a more canonical name to things (`logging` vs `logs`)?

**Hypothetical scenarios**

Person producing tags:

- .Net 4.0 was just released (or just put in beta).  I have a problem with a .Net 4.0 feature, `dynamic`.
- I made a single change in a check in, upgrading my project to target .Net 4.0.  It still compiles, but it fails to run on client machines.  Similar upgrades went right, so this must be a 4.0 specific problem.
- I am writing a program and I happen to be targeting .Net 4.0.  I may or may not be using 4.0 specific features.  Heck, I might only be using 2.0-specific features.

Person consuming tags:

- I am interested in features new to .Net 4.0.  Or, 2.0 is ancient news so I don't really want questions that target those features.
- I have a problem that is 4.0 framework specific, and I'm about to ask a question.  I'm searching to see if someone already has my problem, so I filter based on tag.
- I want to watch and answer .Net questions because I have an expertise in them.

All of these have two sides to them that may or may not be impacted if version-specific tags are removed, or questions are inappropriately tagged.

I am having a hard time seeing how these are addressed by the tag synonym feature, and which are supposed to be addressed by it.  Maybe that means version specific tags should stay non-synonyms, and the tags' usages should be corrected when necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version-specific tags shouldn't be made synonyms of their master tag.

Once a synonym is in place (say [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) <- [bar](/questions/tagged/bar)), if a user puts [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) on their question, then [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) will be saved and displayed instead.

If you make a versioned tags a synonym of its master tag, then people will not be able to use the version tag at all, which beats the purpose of letting us have version tags at all.

---

In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with tagging questions with [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) and [foo-2.0](/questions/tagged/foo-2.0) - it makes sure that people that generally follow [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) see the question, and that they are aware that you're interested in things that work for that version. Makes searching for version-specific things easier too.

Comment: That makes sense for why I wouldn't add a synonym so I've accepted your answer.  As for the rest of it, I think the advice you give on when to add a version specific tag [conflicts with advice that was previously given](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags).  Although that advice is also self-contradictory, so who knows...

Comment: Well, you might want to wait for other answers then, my opinion can be different from that of others. So I think you might want to un-accept  to make sure people look at your question.

Comment: I think the "synonyms remove the version-specific tag" is a compelling reason not to make version-specific tags into synonyms.  There has been a proposed use for version-specific tags, it's just that the advice is broken.  I don't think that impacts the synonym issue.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to make it more clear that the second part of it is just my opinion.