# Tag policy: include superset tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the policy on tagging questions with supersets of tags?

For instance, the tag [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is a superset of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) because if a question is tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) it must by definition have something to do with C++. Personally I don't find it very helpful, to tag such a question with both [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), because that is utterly redundant information (note: **if** you argue that there might be a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)-tagged question which does not deserve the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, then apparently I chose an invalid example, but the question remains).

1. Now, what is the consensus on this problem?
2. If it is contrary to my intuition: Why does it make more sense to always include supersets?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience, the [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) tag is used for all *Mathematica* related questions, including those that are version specific, also bear [mathematica-8](/questions/tagged/mathematica-8), etc.  I think this is very helpful, as I only have to view one tag page, yet I can also clearly see the domain of version specific questions.  If the questions did not have the generic [mathematica](/questions/tagged/mathematica) tag, I would likely miss them.

Comment: That's why you can add `mathematica*` to your list of favorite tags.

Comment: @Null Unless I am missing a feature, there is no easy way to view only questions with favorite tags.  If there is, that would weaken my position.

Comment: Isn't the current front page good enough ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting perhaps

Comment: @Conrad no, that shows piles of stuff I don't want to see, and very little of what I do want to see.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well you can set up a filter at http://stackexchange.com/filters but its a but klunky

Comment: @Conrad, I took another look at that.  I had not realized I could filter for multiple tags at once.  That is a valid solution, so I guess my answer above is not particularly relevant.