# Should I remove generic tags, where specific tags are also used?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag policy: include superset tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113931/tag-policy-include-superset-tags)

Consider a question about "Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011" (my area of speciality). If a user asks a technical question, they may (incorrectly to my mind) choose to tag the question thusly:

[crm](/questions/tagged/crm) [dynamics-crm](/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) [dynamics-crm-2011](/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-2011)

Particularly in a case where the question relates to features only available in the latest version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM (i.e. 2011) am I correct to edit and remove the superfluous tags which implicitly lie higher-up in the tag taxonomy?

Note that I consider this question to be sufficiently different to questions about "inappropriate tags".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OK so not withstanding some overlap with the linked question (and [the question linked from there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags)), I still feel we lack a canonical answer to this "issue".

Comment: I know I prefer having the generic tags.  I like to be able to look at [tag:C#] questions without needing to build a filter for C#+C#4.0+C#3.5+...

Comment: For this we can set bounty on the duplicate question, there is "Canonical answer required" option. Personally I'm pretty much on the fence here but you or someone with more rep who supports your opinion can easily start a bounty there.