# Why were the helpful tags removed from my question

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I asked a question a while ago about the [Equivalent of Unix time command in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8090486/539542) and I tagged the question with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and [powershell-v2.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0).

User `jpblanc` added one more tag: [powershell-v3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0) with the explanation that the question will get the audience of Powershell V3 testers.

I noticed today that user `JasonMArcher` had removed the [powershell-v2.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) and [powershell-v3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0) with not much of an explanation other than *"edited tags"*.

I really thought the removal of those two version tags was not appropriate, since so many questions have those version tags and users specifically target the version tags when asking questions. So having the version tags is definitely helpful.

Is the user justifed in removing those tags from my question?

I wanted to find out before retagging the question.

Comment: "edited tags" is filled in automatically when someone retags a question leaving the summary field blank.

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh really? I always type out "Edited tags." Ha, I must be an overachiever.

Comment: Oh, thats an automatic summary for retags? One more thing I learnt today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Tags aren't a mechanism to attract attention to posts, they're for categorization.**

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) is the correct tag to use for general questions.  More specific tags exists purely to filter out the general questions and leave the specific.  There is no advantage to having them if they are applied to the general case.  People who follow [powershell-v3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0) will also follow [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) if they want to see general questions, and won't if they don't.

Answer (score 12):

Does it matter which version of PowerShell your question applies to? If it doesn't, there's not much of a point having those extraneous version tags there.

If the version really, really matters, you can roll it back. But if your question is just a PowerShell question... I don't think having version tags are that helpful; I wouldn't bother adding them back.

For more information on version-specific tags, see [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags)

Comment: The reason I feel that the tag PowerShell-V3.0 would help is to get the notice of people who directly or indirectly work on V3.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I see using multiple tags not a bad way of going. I know when I start looking to answer questions - I start with PowerShell V3 tags (as a beta tester these interest me most just now), then I start looking at PowerShell V2 and only then PowerShell.

I can't see the harm in adding extra tags in - I've just added some to another post just a few minutes ago!