# Tagging policies for protocols and some of their implementations (e.g. LDAP)

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just noticed that a user had removed the `ldap` tag from this question (and replaced it with `novell`): [How to connect to LDAP Novell using SSL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818175/how-to-connect-to-ldap-novell-using-ssl-in-c)

The way I read it, this question is clearly about LDAP, so it would make sense to have the LDAP tag.

By coincidence, I also found that the same user had also remove the `ldap` tag from another question: [Documentation on LDAP authentication in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791039/documentation-on-ldap-authentication-in-java), which also seems to be on-topic for LDAP.

Looking at [this user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810802/terry-gardner?tab=activity), he's done this for a number of LDAP-related questions.

The [`ldap` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ldap/info) (in fact written by this user) says the following:

> Questions that are specific to Active Directory should not be tagged
>   with the LDAP tag unless the question is specifically related to the
>   protocol or the Directory Information Model. Active Directory provides
>   an LDAP interface, but that interface does not fully implement the
>   LDAP standard, and deviates from it in important ways. Therefore,
>   there are questions that can be answered specific to Active Directory
>   that are not applicable to standards-compliant LDAP servers and vice
>   versa. Correctly tagging a questions will result in a higher
>   probability of an accurate, timely response.

This sounds like the reason behind this un-tagging, although that's not quite the way I would personally have interpreted this. This would seem to go against the guidelines specified [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/148833) (although it's about versions, not specific products).
In particular, if there was a question that's about Active Directory and its LDAP interface, I would have tagged it with both `active-directory` and `ldap`, if only to increase the chances to get an answer from someone who knows about the subtle differences between the LDAP standard and the Active Directory implementation.

Is there a policy for this?

(I must say I tend to look at the `ssl` tag and answer a number of questions there. If someone started un-tagging `ssl` or `tls` when it's an `https` question, I wouldn't necessarily notice them. It seems that un-tagging for similar but non-synonym tags reduces visibility.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed the paragraph you referenced from the `[ldap]` tag wiki body.  While Active Directory may not implement the LDAP standard "correctly," Microsoft still refers to it as an LDAP interface, and so tagging a question with both `[active-directory]` and `[ldap]` refers to *Microsoft's implementation* of LDAP in Active Directory.

The use of tags should not be the subject of pedantic wars relative to the veracity (or lack thereof) of a protocol implementation.  That's like saying you are forbidden from tagging a question with `[table]` `[layout]` because using tables for layout is "bad".

I'm a bit mystified by the removal of the `[ldap]` tags from some of the questions.  Tags should only be removed from a question if the tag clearly has nothing to do with the question.