# New tag should be created: playframework-1.0

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

As Play! Framework has been definitely divided into 1.x+ vs. 2.x+ versions, that would be quite useful if users could tag their questions with exact version also for 1.x, [playframework-1.0](/questions/tagged/playframework-1.0) (in opposite to existing [playframework-2.0](/questions/tagged/playframework-2.0) tag)

#### Edit

As I can see, there are 2 new tags now for Play version 1.x: [playframework-1.x](/questions/tagged/playframework-1.x), and [playframework-1.2](/questions/tagged/playframework-1.2).

Comment: So... you want a separate `playframework-1.x` tag aside from the regular `playframework` tag? Will this be all that helpful?

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion. Play Framework has two simultaneous branches 1.x and 2.x and both are valid (still maintained). There's a lot of questions on SO tagged with `playframework` only, and there is not clear if user is asking in context of 1.0 or 2.0 version of Play. Similar approach is currently suggested at Google Groups for Play Framework.

Comment: [More info on version-specific tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744)

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: That's the clue: Play Framework's versions differs as much that, they CAN NOT be mixed in any way.

Comment: If this tag is created it should be named playframework-1.x - with the x since we're currently on 1.2.4, and not 1.0..

Comment: Can we reach a decision plz? My vote goes to the first answer, two tags playframework-1 & playframework-2, no need for the -x.

Answer (score 4):

Hm, I do not really agree here. I've been retagging a lot of questions recently before reading this post. I've been tagging :

- **playframework** for 1.x
- **playframework-2** for 2.x

Creating two tags **playframework-1.x** and **playframework-1.2** is ridiculous. There is no difference between them. Plus the whole point of tagging is that the tag is popular and might help the question be answered. If you create many tags, they will be less used, thus less popular and tagged questions less answered.

**EDIT** : After a little digging, searching, thinking, my suggestion. Three tags :

1. **playframework** : The general tag for general purposes, architectural, comparing between versions and other.
2. **playframework-1.x** : Playframework 1 related questions
3. **playframework-2.x** : Playframework 2 related questions

**EDIT** : I don't know, but when I see this, I think it is about time we reach a decision. In order not to mess up the whole tagging.

[image: imgur]

Answer (score 4):

My vote is for two tags only:

`playframework-1.x` -> this branch is mostly backward compatible between minor versions

and

`playframework-2.x`

According to some discussions on the playframework mailing list the 1.x branch is considered "feature-complete"; there will only be maintenance releases. There's no point for 1.0, 1.2, etc tags.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe merge all 1.x tags into 1.0? So there will be 3 tags: 1.x, 2.x and general one.

Are 1.1 and 1.2 so different between each other, and 2.0, so should exists independently?

Comment: That was my initial intenion

Comment: No need for the general tag, as said before, the two versions are totally different and there no points common to both versions.

Comment: @Zenklys: Do you know any precedent on SO to do not have a general tag at all?

Comment: No, but why would you need a general tag if there is nothing common between the different versions?

Comment: @Zenklys: I don't believe they are SO different.

Comment: I work with both versions, Play 1.x since about a year and a half. Play 2 since January and the RC release. I can garantee you, there are very few points common between each version. Questions related to version 1 are really version 1 specific. And same for the version 2.

Comment: The general tag (playframework) is the one with links across the interweb, including [www.playframework.org/community](http://www.playframework.org/community). Aren't we slightly braking the internet by not including the current version with the general one? I certainly vote for a general, 1.x and 2.x tag and keeping within [Jeff's version answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags/85744#85744) , but not for not including 2.x answers within in the general tag.