# should version numbers of technologies be it's own field?

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags, outdated-information

I never have any idea what version somebody is talking about. I've encountered version specific bugs in any number of libraries. Wading through questions/answers to find appropriate solutions are never sorted by version really.

any thoughts on some sort of technique to indicate versions without being a hassle or get in the way? As SO gets older and older, I can see this becoming an issue.

Haha, what if in addition to tags there was a machine-learning enabled version suggestion dropdown =)

Glancing at .NET quickly, i see about 116,000 marked. Only about 9,000 indicate 2.0, 3.5 or 4.0 totalling about 7%. Maybe that's too static an example. I can see it's use for fast developing technologies.

Imagine a world where you did not waste 34 minutes reading answers to a question that only fixes it in the wrong version...

Comment: Can you offer an example where the tag system is not working? There are many tags regarding a specific version of a technology. Visit http://stackoverflow.com/tags, and enter "1" in the search box, for example.

Comment: a quick example. .net has about 116,000 tags, out of those only 9,000 indicate 3.5 or 4.0 or 2.0 so roughly only about 7% have an indication of version. Just a quick observation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use version specific tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags)

Comment: haha everyone one think.

Comment: "haha everyone one think" What?

Answer (score 8):

The reason that version-specific tags are discouraged is because the version hardly ever matters.

Most of the answers to [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) questions are the same answers as you would get, whether the question was tagged [.net-2.0](/questions/tagged/.net-2.0), [.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5), or [.net-4.0](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0). Thus, the version-specific tags are just noise, providing no useful information whatsoever.

If the question *does* hinge upon a particular version, then you should use the version-specific tag.

I don't understand what isn't working about the tag system currently. You say that

> .net has about 116,000 tags, out of those only 9,000 indicate 3.5 or 4.0 or 2.0 so roughly only about 7% have an indication of version.

But as I've explained, that's entirely by design. The version number only matters for that 7%.

Comment: i'm not even advocating putting them in tags. I'm asking if it were to happen how might one try to categorize such things. you assumed I wanted tags.

Comment: @FlavorScape Tags are how we "categorize...things". The point is that we don't want to categorize things by version number unless the version number is relevant somehow. And if it is, we use tags.

Comment: What about cases of rapidly developing techs? Most users can't even create tags for them. JXQL

Comment: Seeing this again, especially in frameworks like MVC. Is it MVC3 or MVC4? Who knows, just gotta read a bunch of information that doesn't apply. I have to wade through eons of text before I can, for instance, figure out which version of entity they're talking about.