# "Undo edits" privilege?

Tags: feature-request

It has been a long time since I did write a question, and I have been surfing SO for learning, answering, voting and occassionally reviewing edits.

Lately I found that review queues were flooded with ridiculously minor edits, later I understood that it was due to the new policy of rewarding accepted edits, the annoying opinion from some (too many) newbies that somewhat SO is a "game" where all that matters is the "score", and the complicity of some (from my point of view) sloppy reviewers.

I have no trouble with my spelling is corrected or my format improved, but I think that SO "gamification" is adding each time more noise to the people who uses SO just for Q&A.

I think it is kind of a paradox that I am granted the rights to delete other users posts while I am unable to prevent this kind of annoyance for my own posts from people who has been a couple of months in SO. So, I propose that a new privilege is setup so users that have say, more than 5k or 10k points (so it can be asumed they know how to behave) can revert any edit to their posts (independently of reviewers), removing the editor points. Also I would suggest lowering the cap for getting edition rewards to 1000, so such editors get to "win" faster and cause less polution of the site. For grossly inapropiate posts, the "flag" option would be still effective, though.

OTOH, if the SO bunch is for gamification because they think it suits them better, then I would propose going forward to it and begin renaming the privileges and badges with things like "Master Jedi", "Iron Man", "Dragon Ball Super Warrior" and so on... X-D

EDIT:

Since all of the comments & answers to this point refer to the "but JPS *is* Java" point, I have edited the example of my post to to (if possible) redirect the discussion towards to the privilege proposal I exposed (sorry for the comments & answers that get outdated, I accept full responsability for them). Even if the issue with my posts could be pointed only to the horrible way in which I tag questions, as a editor I still see the issue with many ridiculously minor edits that seem fueled by the points issue, and I think some measures are needed to discourage them (options are welcomed).

Comment: Why *can't* it be tagged [[tag:java]]?

Comment: Tagging a question with [tag:java] puts it in front of the many, many eyeballs watching that tag. It also enables syntax highlighting for any code in the question. You should not remove a language tag unless it's flat out wrong.

Comment: @michaelb958 because the question is specific to JPA. The Jedi Master of Java would not be able to understand any of it, if he does not know JPA. A guy who knows JPA but still does not know what `Cloneable` is supposed to mean can help.

Comment: @JohnKugelman good point about the syntax highlighting, did not know it. As I explained to michael, I feel that it is in my best interest to attract the *specific* eyes than the *most* eyes (I sheldom enter a question that has 3 or 4 catch-it-all tags). Also, keep in mind that also affects me as a reviewer (it is one of the reasons I almost do not review anymore).

Comment: There are a great many topics I'm familiar with (he says modestly), I certainly do not search for them all on a regular basis. I do however search for [java], not tagging something java related as java is like throwing it into a black hole never to be seen again. Whether I know what the J stands for in JPA is ultimately irrelevant if I never see your question in the first place

Comment: @SJuan76 I hear your pain and see your point,  but if the code itself is written in Java language then having it tagged with [tag:java] is not wrong. Maybe not 100% right but also not wrong, even if only for sake of code highlight.

Comment: Re edit: O yes, there are a lot of bad edits, like the 100 bloody [ender invalid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221611/is-the-ember-invalid-tag-acceptable) retags. The answer of course being reviewers doing their jobs properly

Answer (score 4):

If it is related to Java, which it appears that it is, I do not see any harm in adding the Java tag. The point of tagging is to adequately categorize the question and give it the attention it deserves. Did you consider that the reason your question didn't get any answers is because it was so narrowly tagged? There are some tags that really are 'big picture' tags to get the question into a bucket and others that aim to narrow the focus within that big bucket. Think genus/species. Genus in this case JAVA, species, JPA. Just my opinions on the matter. Cheers.