# Proper warning procedures for outdated answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been doing Ember (really vague library) and have used StackOverflow to get some clear answers, because posts are real-world situations rather than some half-baked boilerplate code. Well anyways, I dug up some year old answers that were highly voted and seemed to make sense, but then when I tried them out, they no longer work. I found out that they were outdated already.

What is the right thing to do to warn future users that a post is outdated?

- Should we put something like `[OUTDATED]` in the title? This could ward off users who are Googling for it. The title alone can save them time from actually reading it.
- Should there be an <kbd>outdated</kbd> tag? This would be easy for mods to do some cleanup someday if they decide to remove outdated posts.
- Edit the post or something like an "Alert: Post has not been updated for N months. It may be outdated.", similar to blogs.

Also, things to consider:

- The poster may not be active anymore.
- The answer's owners might not be active as well.

It's like community work from there onwards. I have read several of these "outdated posts" queries here at Meta, but they all seem to say "leave them alone". There's no recommendation as to what to what action should veteran users do in order to keep them helpful or prevent future users the hassle of even trying them out.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115320/what-to-do-about-deprecated-questions-answers or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers

Comment: And http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221611/is-the-ember-invalid-tag-acceptable, which is specifically about outdated ember.js questions on SO. The solution I suggested in my answer there is to re-tag them as e.g. `ember-0.x`. Alas, nobody seems to have actually done that (and I don't know enough about ember to do it myself).

Answer (score 6):

> Should we put something like [OUTDATED] in the title?

No, it would be wrong (misleading). The question is not outdated, the answer could be, but the answers have no titles.

> Should there be an [outdated] tag?

No, for the same reasons as above.

> I've been doing Ember (really vague library)

If the library changes so rapidly, that there's no forward compatibility, the questions should be properly tagged ([ember-x.yy], not [ember]) and the answers should also have details on version that was used. Try to enforce that, making comments for OPs. If the answer is obviously not working, and no version in which it is supposed to work, leave comment. Consider downvoting, if the AP is not reacting.