# Stop closing Stack Overflow questions

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons, off-topic, mso-mse-split

**The proper response when you see an old question that should be on Meta Stack Overflow is to flag for migration.**  Please stop closing these as off-topic, that's not appropriate.

Yes, it would be nice if they had an off-topic close reason to allow migration to MSO, but they've told us they won't be implementing that and to just flag these questions for the mods to deal with.

See Shog9's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges/231505#comment760885_231505).  TLDR:

> Migration is still kind of a pain; if you find something good that's closed, flag it.

Comment: Why is flagging the _proper_ response? Why do we need to involve a moderator? Isn't it easier for the OP to just (re)post their question on the correct site?

Comment: Closing the question doesn't automatically reject all pending custom mod flags to migrate the question to MSO...If the mod wants to migrate it, they can, even if it's closed as off topic.  That said, they specifically said that topics that are SO specific, but that aren't currently under discussion or pending a community response shouldn't be migrated, but closing them *is* appropriate.

Comment: @Yannis, see the last comment on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231505/13295) from Shog9 (always forget how to permalink a comment).

Comment: @LanceRoberts: copy the link address from the comment's time stamp.

Comment: @LanceRoberts How do you go from "if you find something good that's closed, flag it" to "The proper response when you see a question that should be on Meta Stack Overflow is to flag for migration. Please stop closing these as off-topic, that's not appropriate"??? There's nothing inappropriate about closing. If you find something **good** that's closed, flag it.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, edited it into the question.

Comment: Shog's comment simply says that if you find a closed questions that is worth migrating, flag it.  That doesn't change the fact that not everything that's off topic should be migrated.

Comment: Closing in not the right thing to do to a question that was on-topic, and only became off-topic because of logistical changes.  It should be migrated, and migrated in the open state.

Comment: Flagging for migration is the worst possible action and those flags will be declined. It's either joining forces and close them all then slowly delete as Shog suggested, or let them stay buried.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, it's wrong to delete valid questions.  They should be migrated to the proper site, MSO.  They really blew it not starting out migrating all with the stackoverflow tag.

Comment: @LanceRoberts no. Think we'll have to agree to disagree about this. (Or not, anyway I won't stop closing)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, then you're completely changing the paradigm of what closing is for, and for what migration is for.

Comment: Try to think about it as migrating programming questions from the old MSO to Stack Overflow. Even when we got valid and good question, we never asked to migrate it. We closed it as off topic then deleted. Same here: if something is good enough it can be simply re-posted in MSO.

Comment: @LanceRoberts You know questions older than 60 days can't be migrated, right? Flagging old SO specific questions on MSE will be a waste of everyone's time...

Comment: @LanceRoberts It appears you haven't read much of any of the discussions on the migration.  They've explicitly said several times that they're not going to try to migrate very single SO specific question over to MSO.  They're only going to migrate a small percent of the content that is either extremely important to move over, or is recent and under active discussion.  The rest can be closed, and not migrated.  Note, again that closed != deleted.  You're constantly equating these radically different operations.

Comment: @Yannis, that would eliminate ALL MSO questions and make the split completely worthless, since all the old SO-related questions and history thereof would be lost.

Comment: @Servy, no, you obviously don't have the experience on this site to know that many others have de-facto conflated closing and deleting, and I have always been fighting against that siamese twin perspective.  There is no logic to close these questions, if we're going to split the sites then all SO-related questions should be migrated, or else they JUST LIED TO US about the split actually doing what they said it was going to do, i.e. make Meta Stack Overflow the meta site for SO.

Comment: @LanceRoberts actually they were very clear from the beginning, telling that not everything will be migrated, only what would be deemed important enough. Retag requests for example are not important enough, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I agree that `status-completed` retag requests probably aren't important enough to bother migrating, but certainly open ones should be; otherwise, they'll just all be recreated.

Comment: @Lance Maybe new requests posted here by mistake. Otherwise can't really see any point migrating year old retag request, even if still open.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Since the bulk of useful SO specific questions has already been migrated to MSO, I don't see why "old SO-related questions and history thereof would be lost" is something to lose sleep over.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It's precisely because I *do* have a lot of experience on the site that I *can* say that you're erroneously conflating deletion with closing.  You're simply equating them because you seem to think that anything ever being deleted is a crime against humanity.  It's not.  Some things should be deleted, some shouldn't.  The *large* number of closed questions visible through search is evidence alone of this.  Once again, it seems you haven't read through most any of the announcements as to how the split is going to happen.  They have been clear on what should be migrated.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thanks, edited.

Answer (score 12):

If it's off-topic, it should be closed, and questions dealing with only Stack Overflow are off-topic. If you feel like some of the questions are worthy of migration, close *and* flag them. It doesn't matter if the question is closed, diamonds can open it with a click of a button. There's no reason they, like any other off-topic questions, should stay open until the flag is either accepted, and the post migrated, or declined in which case the question should be closed anyway.

Deleting the closed, but apparently useful questions is another matter entirely, and I don't have a firm opinion about it at the moment.

Comment: It's *two* clicks. ;p

Comment: @BilltheLizard Close enough :p

Comment: @Stilly.stack I'm not saying people should actively find these to close them, but if you happen to run across one, it's still off-topic and, hence, close-worthy. Also, link to the transcript, please.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the posts under the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag that were not migrated are old.  Maybe not old in the traditional sense, but old in the sense that they have been forgotten, or the discussions related to those posts are out-dated.

Seriously, is a still open retag request from 2011 still relevant?  Whatever discussion the existed on that post is most likely out dated, or the post itself has just been forgotten.

While some of these topics might still be relevant, it is much better for the discussion to start it over from the beginning by reasking on MSO.  If the topic has merit, reasking will hopefully inject new life into the post and not let old discussion drag it down.