# Tag suggestion: Laravel-4

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Can somebody with suitable reputation create the `Laravel-4` tag? Laravel 4 is the under-development next version of Laravel, a popular PHP framework. It incorporates a number of very big differences from previous versions, and questions asking about Laravel 4 features won't apply to previous versions of Laravel, thus it makes sense to have a separate tag for it.

Examples of questions relating specifically to Laravel 4 include:

- [Laravel 4 class loading and facades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710617/laravel-4-class-loading-and-facades)
- [Laravel 4: save a polymorphic relationship's record: undefined method newQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694319/laravel-4-save-a-polymorphic-relationships-record-undefined-method-newquery)
- [Laravel 4: Working with relationships in seeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666277/laravel-4-working-with-relationships-in-seeds)
- [Laravel 4: Using views in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678209/laravel-4-using-views-in-a-package)

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've added a Laravel-3 tag. This way questions can be specific to L3 or L4, as well as generic Laravel questions. The Laravel tag alone does not seem appropriate for L3 questions if we have an L4 tag.

Comment: I've gone through and edited a significant number of Laravel questions. There are definitely L3, L4 and 'generic' Laravel questions - so the tags seem to work well

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I only suggested the Laravel-4 tag because there is a clear backwards incompatibility. What about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-use-version-specific-tags

Comment: Exactly - and thats the problem - some of the answers specifically require L3 or L4 - so the you need a tag to say this is a "L3" answer to the problem, or an "L4" answer. i.e. some L3 answers will not work for L4, and vice versa

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I think that's likely to confuse people. I don't see what value that tag adds?

Comment: Its the same theory as your L4 tag. There are specific questions/scenarios which only relate to L3. If you are going to tag Laravel-4, then you should tag Laravel-3. Otherwise just have Laravel tag and be done with it.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, Benjamin. There are a large number of edits in the review queue right now adding the 'laravel' tag to questions that are currently tagged 'laravel-4'. Can anyone suggest the correct approach here? Are there cases where both tags are relevant?