# Retagging questions without version specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There was a lot of discussion already on using version specific tags in questions or not. The conclusion about this can be found in [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/177764):

> I would only use version tags when the question content is *irrevocably* tied to a specific version of something and can *never* be relevant to earlier versions or later versions.

This means a lot of questions are tagged *completely* wrong. For instance, the [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) tag is used a lot for questions which does not specifically need html5.

Another example: Almost all question tagged with [symfony-2.1](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1), [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) and [symfony-2.2](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.2) are specifically related to that version. They are often tagged with one of those, because the starter uses Symfony2.1.x, 2.2.x or 2.0.x.

- Should we retag questions which has wrong version numbers? (if so, that will be a huge job, because version specific tags are almost never used correctly)
- What tag do we need to use if we ask a question about symfony and we are using Symfony2.1.x? Because the question does not belong specific to the version, but the answer can be different for specific versions.
- What if there is a new version released that introduces a BC break which causes the question to be related to a specific version? For instance, the question talks about feature A in version 1.0 and that feature get replaced by feature B in version1.1. Do we need to retag that question with the 1.0 version tag?

Comment: As long as the question is also tagged symfony then don't bother...

Comment: I have the same problem in [tag:ruby]. So many people randomly use [tag:ruby-1.9.3], for example, when it is not necessary.

Comment: As for [tag:html5], I wonder if it is used more like a buzzword than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

When version tagging is attempted using that quoted guideline, I think it is inevitable that:

> a lot of questions are tagged *completely* wrong

because, for all but the most experienced users of a particular software, trying to assess whether that is the only version that the question and its answers applies to is very difficult, and if you are using the latest version it is impossible (until the next version is released and tested).

It is far simpler to use version tags to indicate the version that is being used by the question asker.  The question asker usually knows what version they are using, and the potential answerers usually want to know the version being used by the asker so that they know their answering options.

When this philosophy is applied no retagging should be triggered because the questions can be correctly version tagged at the outset using that of the version that the asker is using.