# What is the naming convention for Tags that need versions

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a common format for Tags that need versions next to them? I'm considering making a Tag but I'm not sure what would be the best practice for SO. The version Tags I would like to create are important to the question as the API changes drastically between versions. This makes code examples and and solutions to issues version specific in many cases.

Here are the potentials that make sense to me

- `<Tag>-<Version Number>` : MyTag-1.0
- `<Tag>-v<Version Number>` : MyTag-v1.0
- `<Tag><Version Number>` : MyTag1.0

The specific tag in my case is "Hadoop", the ones I'd like to make are "0.2", "0.23"

Comment: Show us the actual proposed tag.

Comment: clarification given in the qeustion.  hadoop-0.2, hadoop-0.23

Comment: I can see Hadoop 0.2, but what clarification would Hadoop 0.23 add that you couldn't just include in the body of the question?

Comment: 0.2 and 0.23 are the completely different api's (hadoop's versioning leaves a lot to be desired), they are different enough that there is no interchangeability practically between the two.

Comment: Then go for it.

Comment: I just did using the dashes, "-".  but is there no central naming convention for this?

Comment: Your example is pretty much the convention.  If you search for .NET in http://stackoverflow.com/tags you will see several other examples.

Comment: You mind posting that as an answer? Seems like useful information to know

Comment: I upvoted hjpotter's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered sometime ago by Jeff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/212576):

> In general, you should strongly avoid creating version tags.
>
> I would only use version tags when the question content is irrevocably
>   tied to a specific version of something and can never be relevant to
>   earlier versions or later versions.

Since in your [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181179/what-is-the-naming-convention-for-tags-that-need-versions#comment550485_181179), you are mentioning that there has been a major change in API for the two versions, you can definitely overlook the above excerpt.

As for naming conventions, SE's tag suggestions work very good and the following tags are both the same:

- [hadoop-0.23](/questions/tagged/hadoop-0.23)
- [hadoop0.23](/questions/tagged/hadoop0.23)

and when you create either of them, another one will refer to the first one. I'd prefer using the [hadoop-0.23](/questions/tagged/hadoop-0.23) system of naming as it certainly helps with languages which end with a number (like [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).

As for [hadoop-v0.23](/questions/tagged/hadoop-v0.23) or [hadoopv0.23](/questions/tagged/hadoopv0.23); they are entirely different tags and "**should not**" be created at all.

Comment: I agree.  Use the dash unless it clashes with a language name, and avoid the `v`.